# CVcodeのターミナルの横の問題という項目のエラーが消えません

Tags: python

「Excel×Python 自動化の超基本」という本で勉強しています。

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
def readTempData(fileName):
    df=pd.read_csv(fileName,encoding="Shift_JIS",skiprows=6)
    df.columns=["日付","気温","品質情報","均質番号"]
    df['日付']=pd.to_datetime(df['日付'])
    df["曜日"]=df["日付"].dt.dayofweek
    df["月"]=df["日付"].df.month
    df["日"]=df["日付"].df.day
    return df
def readSalesData(filenName):
    df=pd.read_excel(fileName)
    df['日付']=pd.to_datetime(df['日付'])
    return df

dfTemp=readTempData("気象データ2017.csv")

dfsShop=readSalesData("洋菓子店売上リスト2017.xlsx")

df=dfTemp.copy()
df=df.merge(dfShop,how="inner",on="日付")
x=df[["月","日","曜日","気温"]]
y=df["売上金額"]
print(x)
print(y)

model=LinearRegression()
model.flt(x,y)
print(model.coef_)
print(moedl.intercept_)
print(model.pridict(x))
print(model.score(x,y))
```

Comment: 表示されているエラーの内容を過不足無く転記してください。ちなみにこんなサポート情報があるようです。サンプルコードはダウンロード出来るようですが。[（サポート情報）めんどうな作業が秒速で終わる！ Excel x Python自動化の超基本](http://www.tklab.info/2021/01/excel-x-python.html)

Comment: 「CVcodeのターミナル」が不明です。仮に VS Codeを指しているなら, 「問題」をクリックすると問題点が表示されるはずです。それを示せば回答得られやすいかも

Comment: 「CVcode」とは何でしょうか？　コード自体はエラーなく実行できるのでしょうか？

Comment: 上記コメントで紹介したサポート情報記事のサンプルコードによると、`Chapter8`の`pg35_01.py`が該当してそうですが、色々と入力ミスで不足やスペルミス等が多々あるようです。書籍内容を良く見て入力したソースコードを修正するか、サンプルコードをダウンロードして比較してみるとか、そのまま使うとかしてみてください。